# "separately" and "put together" in this context

Tags: word-request, grammaticality

Conversation between two friends:

> A: My dad bought me a *school bag* and a *wrist watch* yesterday.
>
> B: How much did the cost?
>
> A: I don't know their price **separately** but the **put together** cost us $30.

Are these words fine and in right place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this as it is more natural:

> A: I don't know their price **separately** but the **price put together** cost us $30.

You are referring to the price put together therefore it is appropriate to add the word *price* otherwise it doesn’t fully make sense as to what you’re describing.